# How can I operate on <class 'google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedScalarFieldContainer'>?

Tags: tensorflow

Look the code:

```
for serialize_str in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(records_name):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(serialize_str)
    image = example.features.feature['data'].bytes_list.value
    height = example.features.feature['height'].int64_list.value
```

I print type of height and image, they are both `<class 'google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedScalarFieldContainer'>`, but I know I store a int64 into height, so how should I transform `google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedScalarFieldContainer` to `int64`?

Comment: try example.features.feature['height'].int64_list.value[0]

Comment: If height is a int64 list with many integers, do you have any other way to traverse `google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedScalarFieldContainer`?

Comment: it also implements iterator interface

Answer (score -2):

my you could try

```
num = np.reshape(num,[100])
```

`%100` is the length of your container